# Emacs Org Mode Site: Open External Links in new tab

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I'm in the process of remaking my website so that I can write the content of my website in org files.

**I would like that external links would be opened in a new tab, but internal links, such as those in the automatically generated table of contents, must not.**

I'd rather avoid having to resort to the following kind of solution:

```
+
  #+BEGIN_EXPORT html
  <a href="https://example.com" target="_blank">Site</a>
  #+END_EXPORT
+
  #+BEGIN_EXPORT html
  <a href="https://example.com" target="_blank">Repo</a>
  #+END_EXPORT
```

I'd really prefer that I could create links the usual org mode way.

Does anyone know of a way to do this? Thank you.

P.S. I suspect this isn't very relevant but, in case it clarifies anything, I'm building my site using this code in a `.el` file:

```lisp
(require 'package)
(setq package-user-dir (expand-file-name "./.pakages"))
(setq package-archives '(("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/")
                         ("elpa" . "https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")))

;; Initialize the package system
(package-initialize)
(unless package-archive-contents
  (package-refresh-contents))

;; Install dependencies
(package-install 'htmlize)

;; Load the publishing system
(require 'ox-publish)

(setq org-html-validation-link nil                    ;; Don't show validation link
      org-html-head-include-spcript nil               ;; Use our own scripts
      org-html-head-include-default-style nil)        ;; Use our own styles      
;;      org-html-head "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"https://cdn.simplecss.org/simple.min.css\" />")

(defun read-file (filename)
  (save-excursion
    (let ((new (get-buffer-create filename)) (current (current-buffer)))
      (switch-to-buffer new)
      (insert-file-contents filename)
      (mark-whole-buffer)
      (let ((contents (buffer-substring (mark) (point))))
        (kill-buffer new)
        (switch-to-buffer current)
        contents))))

;; Define the publishing project
(setq org-publish-project-alist
      (list
       (list "org-pages"
             :recursive nil
             :base-directory "./content"
             :base-extension "org"
             :publishing-directory "./public"
             :publishing-function 'org-html-publish-to-html
             :exclude ".*\~"
             :with-author nil         ;; Don't include author name
             :with-creator nil        ;; Don't include Emacs and Org versions in footer
             :with-toc nil            ;; Include table of contents
             :section-numbers nil     ;; Don't include section numbers
             :time-stamp-file nil     ;; Don't include time stamp in file
             :html-preamble (read-file "./layout/preamble.html")
             :auto-sitemap nil)
       (list "blog-content"
             :recursive t
             :base-directory "./content/blog"
             :base-extension "org"
             :publishing-directory "./public/blog"
             :publishing-function 'org-html-publish-to-html
             :exclude ".*\~"             
             :with-author nil         ;; Don't include author name
             :with-creator nil        ;; Don't include Emacs and Org versions in footer
             :with-toc t              ;; Include table of contents
             :section-numbers nil     ;; Don't include section numbers
             :time-stamp-file nil     ;; Don't include time stamp in file
             :html-preamble (read-file "./layout/preamble.html")
             :auto-sitemap t
             :sitemap-filename "blog-archive.org"
             :sitemap-title "Blog Posts"
             :sitemap-sort-files 'anti-chronologically
             :sitemap-style 'list)
       (list "static"
             :recursive t
             :base-directory "./content"
             :exclude ".*\~"             
             :base-extension "css\\|js\\|html\\|png\\|jpg\\|svg\\|webp\\|gif\\|pdf\\|mp3\\|ogg\\|swf"
             :publishing-directory "./public"
             :publishing-function 'org-publish-attachment)
       ))


;; Generate the site output
(org-publish-all t)

(message "Build complete!")
```

Comment: You can define a new exporter, derived from the HTML one, that treats links differently depending on their type. See  the doc string of `org-export-define-derived-backend` and override the definition of `org-html-link` which is the function that transcodes links to HTML. You'll need to check the type of the link (e.g. check if it's `http` or `https` and output an `<a ...>... </a>` with the `target="_blank` attribute; if it's of a different type, just output the same thing that the old function did).